# Performance issue in iOS 7 due to deprecated methods

Tags: ios, ios7

I wonder will there be any performance issue in the app due to deprecated methods? how long can i bear with deprecated methods in iOS7? what if iOS 8 got released and i still have iOS7 deprecated methods in my Code?Any suggestions?

Comment: I want to know the answer too. When developing the app, I use some old classes by other developers that contain some deprecated functions. I haven't have time to change the functions yet.

Comment: @voyage11 : you should update the code. Not because of performance issue, but because if Apple removes these methods in a future SDK, you won't be able to build your app at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well if a method is `deprecated` it means that Apple might remove it in the next version of the framework. This does not mean that they will, but it is better to not use them from the moment they become `deprecated`.

There should not be a performance using with using `deprecated` methods.

So if possible you should not use `deprecated` method, but it will affect your app performance, as you can still run apps that use `deprecated` methods on iOS 7. Like for example the `[UIDevice uniqueIdentifier]` was `deprecated` in iOS 6 and removed in iOS 7 but build for iOS 6 or lower can still call the method. It will not return a value of any use but it will not crash either.

Comment: Well, I'll add a point/suggestion, but as far as I know: If your compiled code (as an app on the AppStore) contains a deprecated methods, it should still work on future versions. But if you update your code, you'll have to change theses methods if they don't exist anymore. For the `uniqueIdentifier`, I think that Apple made a big change it, modifying the response given in iOS7.

Comment: Yes that is true, in iOS 7 SDK the `uniqueIdentifier` is not `deprecated` it is just **not** available any more. It is the best example of a `deprecated` method being removed.

Comment: So if am using a deprecated method which got removed in some future sdk that method wont return me anything but it wont crash, am i right?

Comment: That this up to Apple, there is no set rule for it. For `uniqueIdentifier` this is true, but there are methods/properties in the SDK which have been `deprecated` for some time but still work. So there is no way to say before hand. But it is a good idea to not use `deprecated` methods/properties.

Answer (score 0):

There will be no impact on performance. A deprecated method is a method that will soon be removed from the SDK. A deprecated method in iOS 7 will likely be removed in iOS 8 SDK. You should replace the deprecated methods you're using ASAP.